# can't export using expdp, can't open log and more

Tags: linux, oracle, backup, vmware, expdp

I had been asked to create a table: '/u03/oracle/table/prac_tab.dbf'
and import it to '/u04/backup'

Now, my problem begins when i do the following code:

```
[oracle@haranda ~]$ expdp paris dumpfile=parisbk1.dmp logfile=parisbk1.log full=y directory=paris_dir
```

I had tried doing it in the /u03/oracle and other places, but i always get the same result:

```
ORA-39002: operaci�n no v�lida

ORA-39070: No se ha podido abrir el archivo log.

ORA-29283: operaci�n de archivo no v�lida

ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_FILE", l�nea 536

ORA-29283: operaci�n de archivo no v�lida
```

in English would be something like: (not a valid operation, couldn't open the file log, not valid operation of file, in "sys.util_file" lane 536, not valid operation of file)

My other problem is that i managed to make it in my first test, but I am not able to do so now, meaning I could do it only by mistake. Also, I think i understand the basics, but there is a lot i don't understand so far, if you are able to explain it I would appreciate it.

I will leave the code I had been using to create, grant privileges and create the directory.

```
create user paris identified by paris;

create tablespace practica_tab datafile '/u03/oracle/table/practica_tab1.dbf' size 150m autoextend on next 10m maxsize unlimited;
create tablespace practica_idx datafile '/u04/oracle/index/practica_idx1.dbf' size 150m autoextend on next 10m maxsize unlimited;

alter user paris quota unlimited on practica_tab;
alter user paris quota unlimited on practica_idx;
alter user paris account unlock;
grant resource to paris;
grant connect to paris;
grant imp_full_database to paris;
grant exp_full_database to paris;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO paris;
alter user paris default tablespace practica_tab;
grant datapump_exp_full_database to paris;
grant datapump_imp_full_database to paris;

create DIRECTORY paris_dir as 'u04/backup';

grant read, write on directory paris_dir to paris;
```

Comment: try `create or replace  DIRECTORY paris_dir as '/u04/backup'`  valid only full path. Oracle does not verify directory when create.

Comment: thank you, didn't notice i failed to put the slash before u04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create or replace DIRECTORY paris_dir as '/u04/backup'` valid only full path. Oracle does not verify directory when create.